# Is the pressure uniquely determined by the energy density?

Tags: thermodynamics

I've been trying to figure out how many state functions one needs to fully specify a thermodynamic system. For example, suppose we are given the energy as a function of temperature and volume, i.e. U = U(T,V). Then by the first law

$ dU = \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} dV + \frac{\partial U}{\partial T} dT = T dS - p(T,V) dV.$

Unless otherwise specified the derivatives all assume that T,V are the independent variables.

We can then rewrite this to get

$ dS = \frac{1}{T} \big(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}+ p(T,V) \big) dV + \frac{1}{T}\frac{\partial U}{\partial T} dT,$

which gives the partial derivatives of $S(T,V).$ Since partial derivatives commute we can equate the cross derivatives to get

$\frac{\partial P}{\partial T} = \frac{P}{T} + \frac{1}{T} \frac{\partial U}{\partial V}. $

This can be further re-arranged to give

$\frac{\partial}{\partial T} \big( \frac{P}{T} \big) = \frac{1}{T^2} \frac{\partial U}{\partial V}.$

At this point I will make two additional assumptions, using extensivity. Namely, I will assume that $U(T,V) = u(T)V$ and $p(T,V) = p(T)$. These aren't crucial to my question but are convenient.

We then have that

$P(T) = T \int_0^T \frac{u}{T'^2} dT' + cT. $

This is as far as I was able to get, but the undetermined linear term seems unsatisfactory (it is the limit of $p/T$ at absolute zero, but I have no insight for this). However, I cannot think of a way to eliminate it using the laws of thermodynamics. Can anyone offer some insight? Is it necessary to have a second equation of state to uniquely determine the pressure?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the titular question is yes. I had forgotten to use the third law!

By the third law entropy is constant at absolute zero, so we have

$ S(T,V) = S(T=0,V) + \int_0^T \frac{1}{T'} \frac{\partial U(T',V)}{\partial T'} dT'$,

where the first term on the left is a constant. We thus have that

$\frac{\partial S(T,V)}{\partial V} = \int_0^T \frac{1}{T'} \frac{\partial U(T',V)}{\partial T' \partial V} dT' = \big[\frac{1}{T'} \frac{\partial U}{\partial V}(T',V) \big]^T_0 + \int_0^T \frac{1}{T'^2} \frac{\partial U(T',V)}{\partial V} dT'.$

Invoking the first law, we see that $\frac{\partial S(T,V)}{\partial V} = \frac{1}{T} \big(p+\frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \big)$, so we must have

$ p(T,V) = T \int_0^T \frac{1}{T'^2} \frac{\partial U(T',V)}{\partial V} dT' - T \big( \lim_{T \to 0} \frac{1}{T} \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \big). $

In fact, this linear term agrees with the expression I had gotten earlier, once we remember that at absolute zero, $p = - \frac{\partial U}{\partial V}|_T.$

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this when looking for a way how to derive an expression for $\frac{p}{T}$ as a function of $U(T,V)$, $T$ and $V$. Thanks for that.

Related to your question: I'm not quite sure how the third law plays into this and whether all of these assumptions hold when looking at the absolute zero. But what you showed (not forgetting the constraints):$$\frac{p}{T} = \int\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{T^2} +C(V)$$.

is commonly quoted as a proof of the fact you can't express all of the variables (like pressure here) from $U(T,V)$ as $C(V)$ is an unknown function of $V$. This arises because $T$ and $V$ are not the natural variables for the internal energy $U$; $S$ and $V$ are.

Edit: Yes, you are right, the third law can determine the form of $C(V)$. This problem is in thermodynamics textbooks very often placed right after the chapters about analytical thermodynamics, before the third law is even covered, which explains why do they claim the function is unknown at that stage.

E.g. *K. Blundell, S. Blundell* - Concepts in Thermal Physics - exercise (16.4)