# How can you add pressure and internal energy in relativistic enthalpy?

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, fluid-dynamics

In relativistic fluid dynamics the relativistic enthalpy in natural units is defined as:
\begin{equation}
h = \frac{e+p}{\rho},
\end{equation}
Where $e$ is the total energy density and $p$ is the thermodynamic pressure.
In contrast, the Newtonian enthalpy is defined as:
\begin{equation}
h_N = \epsilon+\frac{p}{\rho},
\end{equation}
Where $\epsilon$ is the specific internal energy and $\rho$ is the rest mass density.

The question:
What are the units of $e$ and $p$ so that I can add them in the definition of $h$ above?

Comment: As you said, they are in [natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#Natural_units_(particle_and_atomic_physics)) where $c=1$.

Comment: True, but it's still very confusing. For example, is it the energy that has units of pressure, or is it the pressure that has units of energy, or am I just missing $c$ or $\hbar$ factor somewhere? How come energy and pressure have the same units in the first place? They're completely different physical quantities (ok, this would be explained by the $c=\hbar=1$ factor).

Comment: There are missing powers of $c$ (as is common when doing Relativity). I don’t remember where they go, but it would be good practice for you to use dimensional analysis to figure this out.

Comment: Have you seen formulas like $E^2-p^2=m^2$ where energy and momentum have dimensions of mass? (Or momentum and mass have dimensions of energy, etc.)

Comment: I’ve led you astray. Energy density and pressure have the same dimensions $ML^{-1}T^{-2}$ without taking $c=1$.

Comment: You're right, the dimensions match, thank you. Still very unintuitive though.

Comment: The dimensions of torque and energy also match, even though they are conceptually different.

Comment: It looks like there is also a little bit more to it: [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187283/is-the-pressure-uniquely-determined-by-the-energy-density)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, following @Ghoster's comments, $e$ and $p$ simply have the same dimensions in both systems of units:
\begin{equation}
e = \underbrace{(M\ L^2\ T^{-2})}_{energy} \cdot \underbrace{L^{-3}}_{per\ unit\ volume} = \left( \underbrace{(M \ L \ T^{-2})}_{force} \cdot \underbrace{L}_{times\ length} \right) \cdot \underbrace{L^{-3}}_{per\ unit\ volume} = M\ L^{-1}\ T^{-2} \\
p = \underbrace{(M \ L \ T^{-2})}_{force} \cdot \underbrace{L^{-2}}_{per\ unit\ area} = M\ L^{-1}\ T^{-2} = e
\end{equation}